# Techniques for picture writing?

Tags: creative-writing, technique

So, the title is unclear. What I mean, is I want to create a piece of writing which the reader does not imagine as "real".

I want the reader to imagine this piece of writing as pictures instead, and nothing happens in the pictures, its just a picture showing things. What techniques can I use in my writing to create this 'picture' effect?

Comment: What's wrong with describing the picture you want?

Answer (score 1):

If you don’t have a narrative story to tell, you probably want to write poetry. You can find lots of articles on the Web that will help you get started writing poetry if you haven’t written any before.

You might even want to write poems in such a way that the shape of the words actually creates a visual picture, which is called [Concrete Poetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concrete_poetry).

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a very interesting idea. I would suggest that you use a lot of description if you don't choose to write poetry, which would be the preferred method of writing in this fashion.

For this, you will definitely need third person. You will have to describe everything meticulously, and switch between the "pictures" smoothly.

Depending on the length of your chapters, I would probably keep it to ten pictures a chapter. Twenty if you are writing an extremely long chapter, but try to keep it consistent so the reader does not get thrown off guard.

You'll want to describe everything about the picture, and in the first few chapters you will want to paint the characters in as effective a way as possible, because there really isn't a way to show dialogue. You might be able to describe little bubbles coming from the character's mouths, almost like in a comic strip.

You will probably have to do a lot of planning for this to be an effective story. You need to split up the major events in the story into their own respective chapters, so maybe you should write it narrative-style first. Then, you can tweak it however you would like and split the scenes up into different chapters.